# Arduino Uno DC-Motor Controller concept clarification

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I just started learning Arduino. I thought about going hands on with a Robot which I want to get some autonomy in. I got stuck trying to understand the motor control for the DC motor. I've tried to look up resources but can't find one that adequately explains my problem.
I can't understand (being a comp sci undergrad) how or what I am doing wrong writing the code for the motor.

My code just for running the motors for a test is :

```
// MotorA
int dir1PinA = 7;
int dir2PinA = 5;
int speedPinA = 6;

//motor B

int dir1PinB = 4;
int dir2PinB = 2;
int speedPinB = 3;


void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode (dir1PinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (dir2PinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (speedPinA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (dir1PinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (dir2PinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(speedPinB, OUTPUT);

  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(speedPinA, 500);
  analogWrite(speedPinB, 500);
  digitalWrite (dir1PinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite (dir2PinA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (dir1PinB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite (dir2PinB, LOW);

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

**I am just trying to run the motor at a certain speed to no avail. I found a sample code that uses the same method to control the motor but has just an extra loop and variable** `speed`.

The test code which works is :

```
//Motor A
int dir1PinA = 7;
int dir2PinA = 5;
int speedPinA = 6;

//motor B
int dir1PinB = 4;
int dir2PinB = 2;
int speedPinB = 3;

unsigned long time;
int speed;
int dir;

void setup ()
{
pinMode (dir1PinA, OUTPUT);
pinMode (dir2PinA, OUTPUT);
pinMode (speedPinA, OUTPUT);
pinMode (dir1PinB, OUTPUT);
pinMode (dir2PinB, OUTPUT);
pinMode (speedPinB, OUTPUT);
time = millis ();
speed = 0;
dir = 1;
}

void loop ()
{
analogWrite (speedPinA, speed);
analogWrite (speedPinB, 555 - speed);

// set direction
if (1 == dir)
{
digitalWrite (dir1PinA , LOW);
digitalWrite (dir2PinA, HIGH);
digitalWrite (dir1PinB, HIGH);
digitalWrite (dir2PinB, LOW);
}
else
{
digitalWrite (dir1PinA, HIGH);
digitalWrite (dir2PinA, LOW);
digitalWrite (dir1PinB, LOW);
digitalWrite (dir2PinB, HIGH);
}

if (millis () - time> 5000)
{
time = millis ();
speed += 20;
if (speed> 555) {speed = 0;}

if (1 == dir)
{dir = 0;}
else
{dir = 1;}
}
}
```

Now I understand there are loops and extra variables but theoretically they shouldn't be required to just run a motor at a certain speed. My question is that *What am I missing from the top sketch that is in the second one but is absolutely critical to the running of the motor?*

I want to apologize in advance if this is a noob moment but I tried and can't find any logic lol.

Comment: This is not C++ code. Why does it have a C++ tag? Tags here have specific meaning, and it's not appropriate just to randomly add them because they have familiar names or you think they might get attention. And what's missing is clearly stated in the comments in the first code. Note in particular the one that mentions *repeatedly*.

Answer (score 0):

In the "working" Arduino code ( <sub>c++ , yes it's compiled by a c++ compiler</sub> ) one of your both motors (B) starts immediately, and the other one  5 sec after reset (or even later)? 
And the immediately started motor changes direction after 5 sec?

Else, try small modifications to the working sample, towards your simplification, to get some more understanding. 
E.g. first remove the "dir" change and "else" part

Answer (score 0):

Okay first I will debug your code, I will make a some assumptions about your hardware since you didn't post any photos or schematics, finally I will provide a working solution.

**Your Code:**

So my first assumption is that your Motor has 3 pins because you're toggling two between high and low, presumably to reverse current, and then one to set the speed.

As I am guessing you know, in order to get a motor to reverse you need to flip the direction the current is going. Setting these pins high and low won't actually reverse the current. Also, the Arduino doesn't really have enough output current to drive a DC motor. You can probably slowly run one. If you want to do more you'll need an external power source.

**Drive a DC motor in one direction:**

This is probably the easiest one to do. You just need a transistor, diode and  resistor. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-spin-a-dc-motor-with-the-arduino.html)

**Drive up to four DC motors in both directions**

If you want to drive your DC motor in two directions then you need to flip the direction the current is going. This seems complex at first until you realize they've already built something for you to do this exact thing. It's called a Motor Control. It's just a shield with a few H-Bridges on it. They're pretty cheap.

I like [AdaFruit's](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield). I have a couple and I built a robot with it not to long ago.

[Tutorial on how to use the Adafruit MotorShield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield)